# Where to process the http response (Worked thread Vs Main Thread)

Tags: java, multithreading

Design decision I've to make below is scenario

1. My Server gets http request from the client (Mobile Device).
2. After receiving the response, From Main Thread I spawn multiple worker Thread, each of them makes call to one more server to fetch the response.
3. Responses from other server has same structure.

Processing the response from other server and normalizing it can be done either of below two places and would like to know pros and cons of both.

1. In the worked Thread
2. Or Main Thread

Comment: Isn't that something based on the requirement that whether the responses received by the worker threads from other servers are inter-related? If not I will normalize in worker thread itself.

Comment: There are independent. I just worried Main Thread is waiting instead it can process the response of worker thread.

Comment: There should be clear segregation of responsibility. Worker thread talks to other servers whereas main thread collates enriches and responds.

Comment: Performance wise is it okay ?

Comment: I don't see a reason why it will impact performance. Choose to implement threadpools else you might end up a larger number of threads making system unstable and non responsive.